# Given two points and two vectors, find point of intersection

Tags: c++, math, vector-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you detect where two line segments intersect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect)

Given two points `a` and `b` plus two vectors `v` and `u` I want to find a third point `c`, which is the point of intersection in the following manner:

```
vector2 intersection(vector2 a, vector2 v, vector2 b, vector2 u)
{
    float r, s;

    a + r * v = b + s * u;
    r * v - s * u = b - a

    r * v.x - s * u.x = b.x - a.x
    r * v.y - s * u.y = b.y - a.y
}
```

Is there any other way than using gaussian elimination to solve this system? Or is this the best (or at least an acceptable) way to handle this?

**EDIT**:
Definition of `vector2`

```
typedef union vector2
{
    float v[2];
    struct { float x, y; };
} vector2;
```

`a` and `b` are also of type `vector2`, because the only difference between a point and a vector is in the the way it is transformed by an affine transformation.

Comment: How is `vector2` defined ? And why are *points* a and b also of type `vector2` ?

Comment: I had my explanation below. but regardless. why vector isn't just a struct? why you need the union and the"array"?

Comment: This question has been marked as a duplicate by  Gareth Rees, Paul R,  Mark Dickinson, and 0xbadf00d because "This question has been asked before and already has an answer.".   **BUT** that question has no accepted answer as of this writing.    I don't think that a question should be marked as a duplicate unless the referenced question has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an assignment problem to me. Here is the logic that will help you write the code.

Let us call the first Ray as `R0`.
Locus of a point on `R0` is defined as `P`:

```
P = P0 + alpha x V0
```

For the second ray `R1`:

```
P = P1 + beta x V1
```

Since they should intersect:

```
P0 + alpha x V0 = P1 + beta x V1
```

`alpha` and `beta` are unknowns and we have two equations in `x` any `y`.

Solve for the unknowns and get back the point of intersection.

i.e.,

```
P0.x + alpha * V0.x = P1.x + beta * V1.x
P0.y + alpha * V0.y = P1.y + beta * V1.y
```

solve for `alpha` and `beta`.

If there is a real positive solution for both `alpha` and `beta`, rays intersect.
If there is a real but at least one negative solution for both `alpha` and `beta`, extended rays intersect.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple math.

But, first, check that you have intersection. If both vector are parallel you will fail to solve that:

```
// Edit this line to protect from division by 0 
if (Vy == 0 && Uy == 0) || ((Vy != 0 && Uy != 0 && (Vx/Vy == Ux/Uy)) // => Fail.
```

Then (I won't show the calculation because they are long but the result is):

```
R = (AxUy - AyUx + ByUx - BxUy) / (VyUx - VxUy)  
S = (Ax - Bx + RVx) / Ux
```

Hope that helped you.

Comment: What is the result if you divide `(a.x - b.x + r * v.x) / u`? Assuming `u` is a vector and `(a.x - b.x + r * v.x)` a scalar?

Comment: @0xbadf00d you correct, it's a typo. I meant Ux...

Comment: What if *Ux=0*? Example: *v1=(0,1)*, *v2=(2,0)* and *p1=(-4,2)*, *p2=(3,5)*?