# Formula to find intersection point of two lines

Tags: coordinates, intersection

How to find an point where line1 and lin2 intersect, if both lines are defined by x,y,alpha where x,y are coordinates of a point on a line and alpha is the angle between the line and x=const?

I tried applying sine theorem but it yields two answers (triangles can be built on both sides of a line). I can check which point forms correct slope with one of the points, but that is ugly.

I can switch to y=ax+b representation, but then I have special cases that I have to worry about. Vertical and horizontal lines should be differently to avoid division by zero in 1/sin(alpha) and 1/cos(alpha) cases.

I am not looking for an implementation in a certain language, just a formula.

These questions are not relevant because they deal with finite line segments, NOT lines.

[Given two points and two vectors, find point of intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256525/given-two-points-and-two-vectors-find-point-of-intersection)
[How do you detect where two line segments intersect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose `line 1` is defined by `[x1, y1]` and `alpha1` and `line 2` by `[x2, y2]` and `alpha2`.

Suppose `k1 = tan(alpha1)` and `k2 = tan(alpha2)`.

Then the formula for the x-coordinate of the intersection is

```
x = (y2 - y1 + k1 * x1 - k2 * x2) / (k1 - k2)
```

> Note: Function `tan` is undefined for angles `pi / 2 + k * pi` (where `k` is an arbitrary integer), so:

if `k1` is **undefined**, then `x = x1` and `y = y2 + k2 * (x1 - x2)`

if `k2` is **undefined**, then `x = x2` and `y = y1 + k1 * (x2 - x1)`

(both are practically the same with exchange of indices 1 <--> 2).

Comment: Is there a way to avoid check for `if(aplha1!=pi/2)`? Angles are guaranteed to be different, but one of them might be pi/2 causing div_zero error for tan(pi/2).

Comment: Thank you for your warning about this special case, I extended my answer to include it.

Answer (score 3):

For a line equation `Y = aX + b`, you can calculate `a = tan(alpha)`.

So if line1 is defined as x, y and alpha, the equation is `Y = tan(alpha) * X + b`.

Now to find b, you need a point on your line. This point has coordinates (x, y).

`y = ax + b`

`b = y - ax`

So you line equation is:

`Y = tan(alpha) * X + (y - tan(alpha) * x)`

Now you only have to solve the lines equation:

`Y = a1 * X + b1`

`Y = a2 * X + b2`

Which is:

`a1 * X + b1 = a2 * X + b2`

`(a1 - a2) * X = b2 - b1`

`X = (b2 - b1) / (a1 - a2)`

Right now you can calculate Y too.

So if we replace, we obtain:

`X = ((y2 - tan(alpha2) * x2) - (y1 - tan(alpha1) * x1)) / (tan(alpha1) - tan(alpha2)`

Simplified:

`X = (y2 - y1 - tan(alpha2) * x2 + tan(alpha1) * x1)) / (tan(alpha1) - tan(alpha2)`

And then:

`Y = tan(alpha1) * X + (y - tan(alpha1) * x`

Comment: Same question applies - what if one line is vertical and tan(90) = infinity?

Comment: You need to check it before doing your math.

Comment: You have no other way if you use this method (there are maybe other methods where you don't need to check it)